# Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you when access requests and invitations

Tags: 2013, permissions, access

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I'm site collection administrator

When clicking on the "Access requests and invitations" we are receiving the issue "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you".

I can access the Requests and Invitations.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue, change the Access Request list permissions. To do this, follow these steps:

1. As a user who has the Manage Permissions Permission Level on the affected site and who also has access to the Access Requests list (for example, a Site Collection administrator), browse to the Access Requests list in Internet Explorer.
2. Press F12 to open the F12 developer tools in Internet Explorer.
3. Click the Network tab in the Developer Tools window, and then press F5 to enable network traffic capturing.
4. Refresh the Access Requests page in Internet Explorer. After the page has loaded, press Shift+F5 to stop capturing network traffic.
5. In the Developer Tools window, double-click the first result in the URL list. This URL will end with "pendingreq.aspx."
6. In the Developer Tools window, click Request body.
7. In the search box, type pagelistid: and then press Enter.
8. The search will highlight the pageListId text. Following this text, copy the GUID after pageListId:. The GUID will be inside an opening { brace character and a closing } brace character as follows: {GUID}
9. Include the opening and closing brace character when you copy the GUID. This GUID is the identifier for the SharePoint Online Access Requests list for your organization.
10. In the browser address bar, enter https:///_layouts/15/ListEdit.aspx?List=<{GUID}>, and then press Enter.

Note The  placeholder represents the URL for the site collection where you are trying to change the access requests—for example, https://contoso.sharepoint.com. And <{GUID}> represents the GUID that you copied in step 8.

11. On the Settings page, click Permissions for this list.
12. Make the necessary changes to the permissions for the list to enable users other than those who are members of the Site Owners group to make changes to the Access Requests list.

[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911390)

Comment: Did this solution help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue now and then when granting access when a user requested access.

If you approve the access request and then go to the Permissions for this site. grant the user access manually to the site and it should allow them to visit the site.